# Android layout XML detected by auto-popup windows, but none of the members are detected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have a layout XML file straight from the tutorial:

**layout/partnertrial_summary.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

In my `Activity` class, I try to use the following code, but if fails:

```
mTabHost = findViewById(R.layout.partnertrial_summary.tabhost);
```

which fails. However, it validates the `R.layout.partnertrial_summary` part in Green, but when I try to auto-popup the members of `partnertrial_summary` it yields nothing.

I assume the XML is valid because it came straight from Android, so it's something I am doing wrong on my end. Note that my `Activity` is not a `TabActivity`, but I thought it would be okay to use a regular one and add a `TabHost`, implementing the appropriate listeners. Correct me if my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mTabHost = findViewById(R.layout.partnertrial_summary.tabhost);
```

replace the above as below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.partnertrial_summary,null);
 mTabHost = (TabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
```

layout can be inflated but cannot be find using findViewById()

Comment: Tried this, but did not help... still does not detect those members. With or without the inflater I was able to see members of other resources, but not this one for some reason.

Comment: once clean and build your project

Comment: Tried the clean + build, no dice.

Comment: Yes, that compiles, but I am not interested in the enclosing layout view, I want the tab host...

Comment: :) Yes, it does... So can you only get a top-level View from findViewById?

Comment: Why doesn't `mTabHost = inflater.inflate(R.layout.partnertrial_summary.tabhost,null);` work?

Comment: findViewbyId work for internal and inflater works only to inflate layouts